# Opening Second Aapp's Specific Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two applications `App1` and `App2` I want to open `App2`'s Third activity from `App1` and I want to pass some values between applications too. How can I do this.?

I have tried this:

```
Intent LaunchIntent =   getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.aap2.MainActivity3");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

But I am getting exception.

```
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3714)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     ... 11 more
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1374)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
01-23 00:18:04.150: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at com.example.aap1.MainActivity1.one(MainActivity1.java:27)
```

Comment: Please Add your exceptions logs with your question.

Comment: I ve added Exception log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here

```
Intent LaunchIntent =   getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.aap2.MainActivity3");
```

here you have to pass the `packagename` but you are passing `Activity` name..that too the above will return the launcher Activity you have set in the manifest file..

For this you need to change your code like this..

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.example.aap2", "com.example.aap2.MainActivity3");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

And set `android:export="true"` for `MainActivity3` in Manifest.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app2", "com.example.aap2.MainActivity3"));
//intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // Make sure this falg is really need.
startActivity(intent);
```

---

Useful resources

1. [Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)
2. [Interacting with Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html)

---

You need to write Activity declaration into manifest as (for second app)

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity3"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true" >
        // Add intent filter if any. 
</activity>
```

Comment: again Im getting exception. Should I add anything to manifest other than activities ?  01-23 00:37:09.670: E/AndroidRuntime(5518): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.aap2/.MainActivity3 } from ProcessRecord{408dbff8 5518:com.example.aap1/10045} (pid=5518, uid=10045) requires null

Comment: @Reshmy Check into Activity declaration of your second application. Make sure that you made `android:exported="true"`.

Comment: I got it from Second answer. Thank you so much for your support

Answer (score 1):

**Use this only if you don't know the Activity Name** and don't pass activity name in it like you did

```
Intent LaunchIntent =   getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.aap2");
```

Otherwise just simply try following method, the usual method to open another activity is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```