# Too much work in main thread, app freezes

Tags: android

Here I make call to an activity, which is a chat application.

The catLog:

```
02-26 12:30:38.996: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:39.196: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:39.516: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:39.996: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:40.066: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:40.207: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:40.896: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:41.586: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:42.266: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:42.486: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:42.556: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:42.826: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:43.316: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:43.777: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:43.826: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-26 12:30:43.866: I/Choreographer(807): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
.   .      .   .      .  
.   .      .   .      .
.   .      .   .      .
```

This is how I start the activity from MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     Handler handler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final  Intent i = new Intent(com.example.mainactivity.MainActivity.this,com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activities.SplashActivity.class);
             handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

How can I prevent this,the app hangs after calling the activity.Whats wrong?

UPDATE:

SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements QBCallback {

    private static final String APP_ID = "7467";
    private static final String AUTH_KEY = "TxRFWfX8tTXQ4gv";
    private static final String AUTH_SECRET = "y-QJrO2j69VTaCs";

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
        QBAuth.createSession(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Error(s) occurred. Look into DDMS log for details, " +
                    "please. Errors: " + result.getErrors()).create().show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result, Object context) {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

You can find Details in  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021687/calling-activity-from-another-application) thread.

Comment: You don't need a post a `Runnable` to do what you're doing.

Comment: Can you show the onCreate() method from SplashActivity? It is likely that which is not running to completion in a timely manner.

Comment: I think Yakiv is on the right lines. Those calls to QBSettings and QBAuth are best run on a background thread or via an AsyncTask so that onCreate() can finish quickly.

Comment: I agree with @NigelK, use an AsyncTask to perform the HTTP requests.

Comment: I tried it, but this problem is already tackled  by the API @SQLiteNoob

Comment: Let's try to narrow down the problem. If you remove the calls to fastConfigInit and createSession in SplashActivity.onCreate, is the issue resolved? I have a feeling the problem is elsewhere in your app. Can you share more code?

Comment: Have you tried call QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET); QBAuth.createSession(this); inside AsyncTask ?

Comment: @ksasq yeah, I tried adding up some buttons and preformed simple actions.That worked.The application also works absolutely fine.However, if I call it as activity, it fails.I also think problem is somewhere else.I'll upload the manifest files of the activities may be I am doing it in a wrong way

Comment: I don't think the manifest is the problem. The issue is that somewhere in your code, you have a long running task (database or disk access, network access, something like that) that is being run on the UI thread, preventing Android from drawing on the UI thread when it needs to.

Comment: @ksasq But in that case, stand alone example should also not work, cause operation remains the same but it's working fine.I don't know if this is something different when called by an activity??

Comment: @jay yes I tried it out.But no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the handler in the main activity is completely useless. The onClick callback is called by the system on the UI thread, and your handler is also bound to the UI thread, so you can just go without it. But i doubt you are getting the problems there, it just a small overhead.

You may want to try to move the calls

```
QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
QBAuth.createSession(this);
```

to a background thread, but they may expect to be called on the UI thread, which will cause some problems.

As your code is 1:1 with the code here: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat , I would first try the sample app to check if the problem can also to be seen there. If yes, just open an issue in the github projet :)

If no, then you are doing something differently, and we will need more code to investigate...

Comment: Thanks for your response.I ran the sample, it worked fine.The quickBlox guy told me the already are configured  to run in another thread,so no need of extra work.

Answer (score 7):

`startActivity(i);` just send an Intent to the system. So you don't need to start activity in seperate thread.

Instead you should do all your hard work from`SplashActivity` `onCreate` method in another thread.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//...
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //...
   final  Intent intent = new Intent(this,SplashActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
 }
}

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
//...
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //...
   new Thread(new Runnable()
   {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      //do loading data or whatever hard here

      runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
          //..update your UI here
        }
      });
     }
   }).start();
 }
}
```

Remeber that you can update your UI only on Main Android(often called as UI) thread.

I suggest that yours `QBAuth.createSession(this);` are opening some sort of Http connection, that why your App gets freeze. Move it to separate thread.

**UPDATE :**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity{

private static final String APP_ID = "7467";
private static final String AUTH_KEY = "TxRFWfX8tTXQ4gv";
private static final String AUTH_SECRET = "y-QJrO2j69VTaCs";

public static class QBAuth{
    private static QBCallback mQBCallback;

    public static void createSession(QBCallback qbCallback) {
        // do request initialization
        mQBCallback = qbCallback;
    }
}

public interface QBCallback{
    public void onComplete(Result result);
    public void onComplete(Result result, Object context);
}

public class Result{
    boolean isSuccess;
    String errors;

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return isSuccess;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean isSuccess) {
        this.isSuccess = isSuccess;
    }

    public String getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(String errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}

private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
            QBAuth.createSession(mQBCallback);
        }
    });
}


private QBCallback mQBCallback = new QBCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        handleResult(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result, Object context) {

    }
};

private void handleResult(final Result result) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Error(s) occurred. Look into DDMS log for details, " +
                        "please. Errors: " + result.getErrors()).create().show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Still the same result,and  `QBAuth.createSession(this) ` is taking  `QBAuth.createSession(NULL,this) ` as arguments in  `Runnable `.Is that fine?

Comment: I thing the bug is somewhere else may be?

Comment: Updated: should be `QBAuth.createSession(mCallBack);`

Comment: Is your QBCallback function ok?

Comment: Please check `QBCallback mCallBack = new QBCallback(){` block gives some syntax error.

Comment: Updated answer. There was missing `;` symbol.

Comment: ... hey, you realy want me to create a working sample of your task here? I've explain your problem created fast example in Notepad, showed how you can deal with it (yes, with some syntax mistakes like `this` must be a `SplashActivity.this`). You should lern some java syntaxis before trying to develop Android Apps. I've just created mockup of your model and showed you an example of it in answer(no syntax errors there, checked in IDE). Check an update. Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts.Well that's not it.Basically I am new to this API, so facing a bit problem.There are no errors, but the problem persist.Let me add some more code and Bounty.

May be the bug is somewhere else.

Comment: Also,the HTTP connection is done itself in another UI thread (which I wasn't knowing)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing :

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

cut from your called activity, and paste in your launcher activity.

```
<activity android:name="com.quickblox.sample.chat.Launch"
 android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```