# Android - Too Much Work In Main Thread

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So for my first Android app I thought I would just make a simple number guessing game against the computer. After following a couple of tutorials and re-adjusting my eclipse standalone version into what would hopefully be a runnable app. However, everytime I press on my 'Guess' button, I get the following error:

---

```
12-24 23:53:11.470      823-823/cartersperkins.whatsthatnumber D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling          CheckJNI (already on)
12-24 23:53:13.300      823-823/cartersperkins.whatsthatnumber I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 111 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-24 23:53:14.350      823-823/cartersperkins.whatsthatnumber I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 372 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-24 23:53:14.830      823-823/cartersperkins.whatsthatnumber D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-24 23:53:18.040      823-823/cartersperkins.whatsthatnumber I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 266 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-24 23:53:20.850      823-823/cartersperkins.whatsthatnumber V/EditText﹕ 500+
12-24 23:53:37.990      823-823/cartersperkins.whatsthatnumber I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-24 23:53:55.115      823-823/cartersperkins.whatsthatnumber V/EditText﹕ 750-
12-24 23:53:55.175      823-823/cartersperkins.whatsthatnumber I/System.out﹕ 0/0
12-24 23:53:59.005      823-823/cartersperkins.whatsthatnumber I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

---

I tried following some of the comments under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049375/too-much-work-in-main-thread-app-freezes) question, but I don't really understand what they are trying to say. Here is my application code:

---

```
package cartersperkins.whatsthatnumber;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Game extends Activity {

    Button mButton;
    EditText mEdit;
    private int targetNumber;
    public int lastMin, lastMax;
    public int turn;

    public String abc;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);



        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.guessButton);
        mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.targetGuess);

        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.targetRange);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());
                gameStart();
                clicked = true;
                xyz = mEdit.getText().toString();


            }
        });


    }

    public void gameStart() {

        Random rand = new Random();
       if(game) {
           turn = 0;
           game = true;
           lastMin = 0;
           lastMax = 1000;
           targetNumber = rand.nextInt(1001);
           System.out.println("The number is between 0-1000.");
           game = false;
       }
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//      System.out.println(targetNumber);
//        while (game)
//
//        {

            if (clicked) {
                range(xyz);
                int a, b;
                if ((lastMax - lastMin) <= 100
                        && (lastMax - lastMin) > 10) {
                    a = rand.nextInt(lastMin + (rand.nextInt(25) + 26));
                    b = rand.nextInt(lastMax - (rand.nextInt(25) + 26));
                } else if ((lastMax - lastMin) <= 500
                        && (lastMax - lastMin) > 100) {
                    a = rand.nextInt(lastMin + (rand.nextInt(100) + 101));
                    b = rand.nextInt(lastMax + (rand.nextInt(100) + 101));
                } else if ((lastMax - lastMin) > 500) {
                    a = rand.nextInt(lastMin + (rand.nextInt(100) + 151));
                    b = rand.nextInt(lastMax + (rand.nextInt(100) + 151));
                } else if ((lastMax - lastMin) <= 5
                        && (lastMax - lastMin) > 2) {
                    a = (lastMin) + (rand.nextInt(3) + 1);
                    b = (lastMax) - (rand.nextInt(3) + 1);
                } else if ((lastMax - lastMin) == 2) {
                    if (lastMax < targetNumber
                            && lastMin < targetNumber) {
                        a = (lastMin + 1);
                        b = (lastMax + 1);
                    } else if (lastMax > targetNumber
                            && lastMin > targetNumber) {
                        a = (lastMin - 1);
                        b = (lastMax - 1);
                    } else {
                        a = (lastMin + 1);
                        b = (lastMax - 1);
                    }

                } else if ((lastMax - lastMin) == 0) {
                    a = lastMax;
                    b = lastMin;
                } else {
                    a = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
                    b = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
                }
                String y = a + "/" + b;
                System.out.println(y);
                range(y);
                clicked = false;
            }
//        }
    }

    public String input(TextView z) {
        return z.toString();
    }

    public void range(String guess) {
        if (clicked) {
            int guessMin = 0, guessMax = 0;
            if (guess.contains("+")) {
                guessMin = Integer.parseInt(guess.substring(0, guess.indexOf('+')));
                guessMax = lastMax;
            } else if (guess.contains("-")) {
                guessMax = Integer.parseInt(guess.substring(0, guess.indexOf('-')));
                guessMin = lastMin;
            } else if (guess.contains("/")) {
                guessMin = Integer.parseInt(guess.substring(0, guess.indexOf('/')));
                guessMax = Integer
                        .parseInt(guess.substring(guess.indexOf('/') + 1));
            } else {
                guessMin = Integer.parseInt(guess);
                guessMax = Integer.parseInt(guess);
            }
            turn++;
            if (guessMin == targetNumber && guessMax == targetNumber) {
                if (turn % 2 == 0)
                    System.out.println("Computer Won!");
                else
                    System.out.println("Player Won!");
                game = false;
            } else {

                if (guessMin > lastMin && guessMin <= targetNumber)
                    lastMin = guessMin;
                if (guessMax < lastMax && guessMax >= targetNumber)
                    lastMax = guessMax;
                if (game) {
                    System.out.println("The number is between " + lastMin + "-"
                            + lastMax + ".");
                    abc = lastMin + "-"
                            + lastMax;
                    mText.setText(abc);
                }
            }
            clicked = false;
        }
    }

    public String getAbc() {
        return abc;
    }

    public void setAbc(String abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    public boolean clicked = false;

    public boolean isClicked() {
        return clicked;
    }

    public void setClicked(boolean clicked) {
        this.clicked = clicked;
    }

    public String y;
    private boolean game;

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(String y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String xyz;
    public TextView mText;

    public String getXyz() {
        return xyz;
    }

    public void setXyz(String xyz) {
        this.xyz = xyz;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Any help or links to help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `AsyncTask` or you can use `Handler` which will be registered with thread and update your all `UI` in its method.

Comment: How do you plan on writing to `stdin` to read with your `Scanner`, on android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Try to use AsyncTask Refer to this Link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object , Object , Object > {
     protected Object doInBackground(Object... urls) {
         // do some thing in background
         return result;
     }
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    // this will execute on main thread before Method doInBackground()

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

     protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
// this will execute on main thread after Method doInBackground()

     }
 }
```

To call this use `new MyAsyncTask().execute("");`

if you have any question ask me.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 2):

U have to use Asyntask.

```
private class DownloadMp3Task extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
  //Yet to code
 }
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
 //Yet to code
 }
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
 //Yet to code
 }
}
```

Comment: what is difference between your answer and my answer ?

Comment: @Nitin : He just trying to explain his own way.... agreed there is no any different...  he just not added super.onPreExecute(), and yes you have been added more generic method here he has added more specific to problem. Thanks Nitin to make focus here.

Answer (score 0):

Thing isnt about that! it just warning not the erro!post the logcat where you get FATAL EXCEPTION.you can do this on main thread only thing is network at which you cant.You might have some another problem just look for FATAL EXCEPTION in logcat!

Answer (score 0):

Those are not error messages by the way. Those are warnings and I have seen those warnings appearing in applications that do a bit of UI work using OpenGL but more so when you are using an Emulator. Try running your application in an Android phone to investigate the logs. They may or may not appear.

Use AsyncTask or Threads to do your intensive job so that it does not hang the main thread. When you do intensive work in UI thread your application will basically not respond. However this will not guarantee that you will not see those warnings. Some are generated by the OS itself while drawing and can be ignored as long as your application is working fine.